# MPAndroidChart X axis labels not aligned

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart to draw line chart in my android project and I see that the labels on the X-Axis are not aligned properly like shown in image below.

[unaligned labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIWLT.jpg)

Comment: what version of library you're using ?

Comment: compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1484) in MPAndroidChart library that was fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/commit/19a98c2c8a0d1a0e84d89e700ab808995b157c1e). so you need to use latest library version as of now latest version is ***v3.0.0-beta1***

Comment: Am facing the same issue.Am using v3.0.0-beta1 Whereas the x-axis labels are shown alternatively. But, it requires to visible all the x-axis on first load.how could i achieve it?

Comment: I'm using v3.1.0. 
but it still showing 6 points instead of 12 x-axis points. are there any solutions?

Comment: I can't help you guys.. sorry maybe you can find a bug there in the issue tracker.